# How to know that the file contains image or video in android?

Tags: android, file

I am new to android my problem is that i select something(image or video), now how i come to know that the selected file contains image or video in android? Help please

Comment: How are you selecting these items? Are they from a list of file names? If they are then are you able to use the file extension?

Comment: u can find the file type by .extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(item.endsWith(".jpg"))
{
//Image
}
if(item.endsWith(".3gpp"))
{
//video
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this may also help you

```
       String mpath ="a1.jpg";

        if(mpath.contains(".jpg")){

        }else{

        }
```